# angularjs: wrong css path on direct access

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs

One angular app using `$location` html5 mode, located in an `app` subdirectory.

when the user makes direct access on a subpage (/thing/123), angular gives a wrong css URL.

for example : the path of the css is `site.com/app/css/styles.css`, but when the user makes a direct access to `site.com/app/thing/123`, this page calls a wrong css path: `site.com/app/thing/css/styles.css`. It is like angular is looking for the css relatively to the current URL. Oddly, the javascript files paths on the same page are correct (`site.com/app/js/scripts.js`).

However, this problem is only on direct access to a subpage. When accessing from `site.com/app/things` and navigating to `site.com/app/thing/123`, the css is loaded correctly.

in `index.html`, the css link tag is like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
```

To solve this, I could set an absolute css path: `/app/css/styles.css`, but I would prefer to keep it relative to the app directory.

The .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(js|html|png|css)
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

How can i solve this wrong css path?

Answer (score 1):

i found prepending the path to the stylesheet with a / solves the problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, together with a htaccess like above:

1. Set the base url, probably in the base index.html:

   `<base href="/">`
2. Use paths starting with / to navigate relative base url

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>`